# Suppose that for every pair of real numbers on $\mathbb{R}$, $[a, b] \in T$. Show that $T$ must be the discrete topology.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $T$ be a topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that for every pair of real numbers $a$ and $b$, with $a<b$, we have $[a, b] \in T$. Show that $T$ must be the discrete topology.

I don't really know where to start, I believe the concept I have in my head of a topology is not very accurate as it is a fairly new concept to me, but if a topology is a collection of subsets which are called the "open sets", how can $[a,b] \in T$ if that is a closed subset? And how do I link it to the discrete topology? I don't really know what I need to check.

Comment: Being closed is something that depends on the topology you consider. $[a,b]$ is closed in the usual topology of $\Bbb R$, but here you are considering another one, for which it is **defined** as an open set.

Comment: The terms "open set" and "closed set" depend on the topology that you work with. $[a,b]$ is closed (and not open) in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, but there are other topologies as well.

Comment: Hint: consider the intersection $[a,b] \cap [b,c]=\{b\}$ Looking at the definition of topology what can you say about this set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a subset to be open/closed is a concept that depends on the considered topology.
What you have in mind is the usual topology of $\Bbb R$, induced by the absolute value $|.|$.
Here, you are considering another topology, for which all subsets $[a,b]$ with $a < b$ are required to be open.
This indeed cannot be the usual topology.

To show that such a topology has to be discrete, it is enough to show that any singleton $\{x\}$ is open.
So let's take $x\in \Bbb R$.
Since $x-1 < x$, by definition, $[x-1,x]$ is open.
Similarly, $[x,x+1]$ is open.
Now, $\{x\} = [x-1,x]\cap [x,x+1]$ is open as the intersection of finitely many open subsets.
This concludes the proof.